# Wait for the response of the Api - Angular js 2

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I would like to put a token in a cookie the only problem and that the cookie is created before getting the response of the API, how is it that I can do to wait for a response and then create the cookie?

My Code

```
getlogin()
{
this._symfonyservice.login(this.user,this.pass).subscribe(//call the post
            data => this.results = data, // put the data returned from the server in our variable
            error => console.log("Error HTTP Post Service"), // in case of failure show this message
            () => console.log(this.results['token'])//run this code in all cases
        );
if(this.results['token']!="")
{
    let token = this.results['token'];
    this.deleteCookie("Cookieteste");
    this.setCookie("Cookieteste",token, 1);
}
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it in `data` instead of `() final function`

```
getlogin()
{
this._symfonyservice.login(this.user,this.pass).subscribe(//call the post
data => {
            this.results = data
            if(this.results['token']!="")
            {
                let token = this.results['token'];
                this.deleteCookie("Cookieteste");
                this.setCookie("Cookieteste",token, 1);
            }       
        }, // put the data returned from the server in our variable
                error => console.log("Error HTTP Post Service"), // in case of failure show this message
                () => console.log('completed')//run this code in all cases
     );
```

Comment: The method **subscribe** is only used for post request right? Or can I use to get request and then use the **data** to execute code.

Comment: you can use it for all **get**,**post**,**put** and **delete**.